# Integer assignment in multi-threaded environment java

Tags: java, multithreading

Read and write operations to reference variables and primitive variables are atomic in java.

Say I have the following class:

```
public class Example{
  private int k;
  public void setK(int k){
    this.k = k;
  }
}
```

As far as I understand it is a thread safe because integer assignment is atomic. But what about visibility? When one thread update k does it means other thead will see the updated value?

Thank u in advace

Comment: You will want a `volatile` variable.

Comment: does a volatile is a must in this case?

Comment: Yes, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand it is a thread safe because...

If you've shown us the whole `Example` class then it is absolutely thread-safe.  Your class is thread safe because *it has no publicly visible state.*

A class is "thread safe" if there is no way for overlapped method calls from multiple threads to put the class or any of its instances into a bad state.  Your `Example` class can't get into a bad state because it does not publish *any* state whatsoever:  The class has only one method, `e.setK(int)`, but that method has no effect on anything that client code can see.

If, on the other hand, you have only shown us part of the `Example` class, then there is no way that anybody can say whether the class is thread-safe or not.  We'd have to see the rest of the class.  Are there other fields besides `k`?  What is the relationship between them?  Are there methods whose behavior depend on the value of `k`?  What promises does your class's API contract make about how an instance will behave for different values of `k`?

Without that information, we can not even begin to talk about thread safety.

Comment: It has only getter for k

Comment: If the class also has an `int getK() { return k; }` method then @manouti 's answer applies because if you don't declare `volatile int k;`, then the value of `k` is _undefined_ when any thread _G_ calls `e.getK()` after some other thread _S_ has called `e.setK(...)`.  There's no point in talking about "thread safety" if your class has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

It is neither thread-safe nor establishes a visibility from one thread to another. It is not thread-safe because `this.k = k;` is a read and write operation. In order to establish the latter, you can have the variable declared `volatile`. In this case, you can also use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).